# SVG border 1px solid grey GMAIL

Tags: html, css, svg, gmail, html-email

I'm trying to send a combined `.svg` + `.png` email following [this](https://css-tricks.com/a-guide-on-svg-support-in-email/#svg-email-bonus) tutorial. Testing with the gmail app (which is not able to load `.svg`) it displays an empty img with a border of 1px grey as I show in the image.

[image]

Here bellow I paste the code of that case:

```
 <style>
   .showy {
     height: 70% !important;
     width: auto !important;
   }
   .no-showy {
     display: none;
   }
 </style>
 <table width="90%" height="100%" style="max-width:510px;margin:10px auto;">
   <tr>
     <td>
       <img class="showy" width="0" height="0" style="max-height:70px; margin:15px auto;" src='data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg ....../></svg>' />
       <img class="no-showy" style="max-height:70px; margin:15px 0;" src="http://example.com/mailing/images/header.png" />
     </td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: If this is an email, your (PNG) image URL will need to be absolute, surely?

Comment: have you tried removing the style from the svg image tag? What happens if you do?

Comment: I tried to remove the style and the problem continued. In addition, I tried to remove the entire `svg` and the square pixel disappeared, so I've figured out that the problem is with the `svg`

Comment: Would suggest just using a .png instead. I've tried loading .svg files into emails before and it's just not worth the hassle.